# Powershell: Installing Modules on Target System

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

When I do this -

```
PS C:\> $env:psmodulePath.split(";")
```

I get two folders - i.e. **User Module Folder and System Module Folder**.

```
User Module Folder
C:\Users\winUser1\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules

System Module Folder
C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\
```

Now, when I am copying my psm1 files under system module folder, and trying to do import-module from ISE x86, the scripts are **not getting loaded**, but vice-versa is true - i.e. working from user module folder.

But, in a production environment, I want any user to be able to execute the scripts. Any idea how to achieve the same ?

**NOTE: I am using Windows 2008 R2 and Windows 7 - All 64-Bit Versions, but scripts should run as 32-bit version**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to copy them under the SysWOW64 folder. The SysWOW64 folder contains the 32-bit system files and the System32 contains the 64-bit system files

C:\windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules

Comment: Cool! It works..But why does the x86 environtment returns a wrong path then ?

Comment: Each environment 'sees' the path (system32\...) as the native path. Obviously both can't use the same location. In 64 environment you can open the 32 location by using the SysWOW64 path.

Comment: And you can access the 64-bit System32 folder from 32-bit PowerShell like so: `Get-ChildItem C:\Windows\SysNative`.

Comment: Thanks, but can I do the vice-versa i.e. retrieve the full 'module' path name of the 32-bit folder in a 64-Bit OS ?

Comment: Get the 64 bit module path and replace System32 with SysWOW64, then test if the module exists in the modified path.