# changing platform for .aspx page that needs x64 to run

Tags: c#, powershell, exchange-server

I have a program that I use to change user passwords for exchange 365.  In order to do this  I use the exchange online module for powershell.  In order to call these modules from my application I have to set it to x64.  I am trying to use the same idea to put a variation of this application on a website so that users can change their passwords from their website.  However, I don't have a way to specify which architecture I need it to be on with a .aspx page.  I am using a web service to perform the operation locally on the server.

Is there anyway I can specify the architecture or any way of getting around this so that I can import the exchange module?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyways the script will always run on the server. So, you can always post the parameters from the UI to the server side code. Hence, you can just do an import-module from the [server side C# code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10723264/powershell-c-invoking-a-pipeline-asynchronously-displaying-the-results). Make sure that the Module is [installed correctly on the target system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10501484/powershell-installing-modules-on-target-system) (x86 or x64)

Comment: I tried it doing it just from the server but it is not working.  I am sure the module works because I can run it from powershell.  I also created a test console application with the same code as the web service and it works fine I can change the password this way.  However calling the web service doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: Try putting a try / catch in the powershell script and debug. When you are running via WebService, that means it is running w.r.t. the IIS / w3wp.exe security context. Could be a trivial issue. You may see my SO post here for exception handling in powershell - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10676875/powershell-debug-in-production-good-exception-handling

Comment: Check if the call from webservice is reaching powershell at all.