# Powershell v2.0 Modules: Default Load Path (User / Windows system folder)?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

This is with respect to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10501484/763026) which I had asked earlier - [Powershell: Installing Modules on Target System](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10501484/763026)

- What is the default module load path ?  
     Now after so many days, it has started giving this error (from my C# code)
   `Cannot find path 'C:\Users\angshuman\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\MyPSModules\MyPsModules.‌​psd1' because it does not exist.` 
    *All the while it was nicely loading from the SysWow64 folder path*
- Why it is suddenly searching in **user** folder rather than **Windows** folder?

**I am executing the same code via C# on a Windows 7 64-bit OS**

```
    _ps = PowerShell.Create();   
    _ps.AddScript("Import-Module MyPSModules -PassThru");
    Collection<PSObject> psObjects = _ps.Invoke();
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`$env:psmodulePath` is the automatic variable which holds the path used to discover modules. If it's not set, PowerShell looks in `c:\windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\modules` and `MyDocuments\WindowsPowerShell\modules`.

So it should by default always be looking in both places.

I haven't done much 32-on-64 coding, but I could see it using SysWow64 (instead of System32) if you were running a 32-bit app on a 64-bit OS.

Answer (score 28):

And if you want to have them to have a better readability you can use this:

```
$env:PSModulePath.split(';')
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately it is not the full list.
Not sure how, but Pscx was installed in different dir and wasn't listed here...

Comment: Hi @Anton That's not possible, at least you install it using an installer and the installer add his root address to that lists. 

You can use this to search where it is installed:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/powertip-find-the-path-to-a-powershell-module/

Comment: Hi @Jose Ortega. Yes, I installed it using installer and forgot about it. Then 3 years afterword I was confused: it is not in list, I don't remember that I installed it.